# Logstash Still using old Data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Im new to ELK and Im struggling with my logstash configuration file. The issue is that the logstash is processing the old data.
The following is the error i get when running with new data:

```
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.


Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::File path=>["C:/Users/MISHAL/Desktop/ELK_Files/jsonTest/jt.json"], type=>"json", start_position=>"beginning", sincedb_path=>"/dev/null", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8">, stat_interval=>1, discover_interval=>15, sincedb_write_interval=>15, delimiter=>"\n">
  Error: No such file or directory - C:/dev/null.14066.5108.511127 {:level=>:error}
```

The Configuration file:

```
input {
    file{
        path => ["C:/Users/MISHAL/Desktop/ELK_Files/jsonTest/jt.json"]
        type => "json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
        match => [ 'message', '(?<body>\"id\":.*\"enq\":\"[^"]+\")' ]
        add_field => [ "json_body", "{%{body}}" ]
  }
  json {
        source => "json_body"
        remove_field => ["message","body","json_body" ]
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => ["[test][enq]","%{[enq]}"]
    add_field => ["[test][bkd]","%{[bkd]}"]
  }
   mutate {
      convert => [ "[test][increasedFare]", "float"]
    }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  } 
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "jst-json"
  }
}
```

Ps: I also tried removing sincedb_path => "/dev/null" and deleting all sinceDB file. Even then it still does'nt process the new data but without any error message.

Comment: I think I found a solution, but not entirely certain if its correct. I removed sincedb_path => "/dev/null" again and In my json data i added each record as seperate lines and then it worked. Its strange I expected logstash to be able to to process standard json format. Please ley me know if this is a correct approach.